# trouble finding substring in array

Tags: c, substring

I'm trying to search through some HTTP headers, and am looking for packets containing "bbc.co.uk".
As far as I'm aware I'm using the methods correctly, but I must be overlooking something obvious, as there isn't a match being found, despite when I print the packet contents out, there are such matches.
Can anyone see the error?

```
 void parseHTTP(const unsigned char *packet, int length)
{
  int i;
  const char *blacklisted = "www.bbc.co.uk/news"; 
  const char *payload[length+1];  
  for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
      char byte = packet[i];
      if (byte > 31 && byte < 127)
      {
          printf("%c", byte);
          payload[i] = byte;
      }
  }
  //char *result;
  //result = strstr(payload, blacklisted);
  //printf("%s", result);
  if(strstr(payload, blacklisted) != NULL)
  {
    printf("Found match \n");
    blacklistedCount ++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give a sample "packet"
Or run output?

Are you 100% sure that the entire blacklisted string is contained in packet?

Comment: The packet, is simply a pointer to the start of the HTTP header, and yes, I've wrote the output to a file and ctrl+f the name and it's identical

Comment: @MartinJames I thought strstrs() returned null if no match was found. The point of thta is saying if a match is found then ... Or am I wrong?

Comment: @DannyLines forget my comment - I'm tired:(

Comment: `const char *payload[length+1];` is an array of pointers.  Do you want an array of `char`?

Comment: the compiler must be screaming at you with warnings about payload

Comment: lol - the dump you provide does not contain the string you are looking for, so whats your question?

Comment: @pm100 apologies, wrong dump

Comment: you must fix `payload` type. it must be `char [xxx]` not char *[xxx]`

Comment: @pm100 warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strstr’ from incompatible pointer type

Comment: never ignore compiler warnings. The compiler is saying 'well this is surprising, I can work a way to guess what you mean but I doubt its correct'. It is trying to help you

Comment: @pm100 I changed it to that, I got an error telling me "assignment of read-only location"

Comment: @DannyLines - remove the `const`

Comment: @pm100 So what is it i'm doing incorrectly with this method? I can't see an error :/

Comment: you really have to learn to read function signatures, strstr takes a char * as its first parameter. you are passing a char*[]. These are 2 different things.

Comment: @pm100 "error: assignment of read-only location ‘payload[count]'" its when I do payload[count] = byte;

Comment: first, make your code compile without warnings. Then if it still doesnt work ask the question again. If you cant work out how to make it compile without warning then ask that as a question too.

Comment: remove the const on payload declaration. you told the compiler you were never going to write to it, now you are trying to

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the ***shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself***. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." All anybody can do is guess without knowing exactly how you fill `packet` before passing it to `parseHTTP`. Nothing can be ***reproduced*** if what you provide cannot be compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give some more specific details.

```
payload[i] = byte;// payload is array of char pointer, what's the need of storing single character into array of pointer, take payload as a single pointer


strstr(payload, blacklisted)
```

strstr() first argument is **char*** but you taken **array of char pointer**.

Modify your code as below :

```
void parseHTTP(const unsigned char *packet, int length)
{
        int i,j=0,blacklistedCount=0;
        const char *blacklisted = "www.bbc.co.uk/news"; 
        char *payload=malloc(length);  
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
                char byte = packet[i];
                if (byte > 31 && byte < 127)
                {
                        printf("%c", byte);
                        payload[j++] = byte;
                        continue;// add this
                }
                else
                {
                        payload[j]='\0';
                        if(strstr(payload, blacklisted) != NULL)
                        {
                                printf("Found match : %d \n",blacklistedCount ++);
                        }
                        j=0;//again make it 0
                }
        }
}
```

modify according to your requirement.

Comment: I'm not surewhat you mean? I'm trying to copy the values pointed to by packet to payload. Then comparing payload with the substring to be found.

Answer (score 0):

In general HTTP traffic, host name and path are typically separate, split like this:

```
GET /news HTTP/1.1
Host: www.bbc.co.uk
```

(plus many more request headers).  So TCP segment containing HTTP traffic will never contain the string `www.bbc.co.uk/news` verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

Your type for `payload` is an array of `char` pointers which is a 4/8 (platform dependent) byte type.
This means that 3 of every 4 bytes in your array are `0` which on most platforms IS `'\0'` so your `strstr` function runs 0-1 iterations, depending on Endianity of your system.

The definition you were looking for is probably `char payload[length+1];`

And while at it - there's also no reason why your `packet` is `unsigned`.

In addition:

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    char byte = packet[i];
    if (byte > 31 && byte < 127)
    {
        printf("%c", byte);
        payload[i] = byte;
    }
}
```

Please note that you use `i` on both `payload` and `packet` - while you skip non-printable characters (or line-down characters for that matter) which are probably contained in `packet`.
When you skip that way, you leave uninitialized data of `payload` in the index you've skipped, which could easily be `\0` terminating the string and stopping `strstr`.

You should also add a trailing `\0` to your `payload` array for this exact reason.

To solve this issue, keep 2 indexes, `i` and `j` - and only advance `j` inside of the if: `payload[j++] = byte;`